# Add elements to Array with map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an Array that I get from Props: `this.arrayContenido = this.props.children;`. If I `console.log` this, i have an array like this: https://puu.sh/Dlsce.png

ok, I need split this array for animate them with gsap. I mapped this array, and assign each element of this array to new array(`this.children =[]` in constructor):

```
{this.arrayContenido.map(function(item, i) {
                return (
                  <div key={i}  ref={div => (this.childrens[i] = div)}>
                    {item}
                  </div>
                );
              })}
```

Why when i do `console.log` in `componentDidMount` for `this.childrens` i have undefined results?

Comment: Typo? Your code says `this.childrens[i]` The plural of "child" is "children", you have "children**s**"

Comment: i dont understand what u say :(

Comment: In the code you use `this.childrens` but in the explanation you wrote `this.children`. Note the `s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have problems with `this`. You can use arrow function to get proper `this`

```
{
  this.arrayContenido.map((item, i) => {
    return (
      <div key={i} ref={div => (this.childrens[i] = div)}>
        {item}
      </div>
    );
  });
}
```

This is assuming that this code lies in the `render` function or any function with the correct `this`, which is the component.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is the anonymous function without binding, `this` won't be what you expect inside it and therefore `this.children` will be undefined. You can use an arrow function instead which provides the auto binding:

```
{this.arrayContenido.map((item, i) => {
    return (
        <div key={i}  ref={div => (this.childrens[i] = div)}>
            {item}
        </div>
    );
})}
```

You were already using arrow function in the ref prop, but not in the surrounding anonymous function...

The second issue is with this.props.children: it shouldn't be seen as an array. If you want to iterate over a React component's children you have to use `React.Children.map(this.props.children, () => ....)`

look into [React.Children](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren) for more details.